# Startup program run before Modern UI?

Tags: boot, modern-ui

I have a desktop (not Modern UI) program that is set to run at startup using the registry key currentversion\run.   I want it to be the very first thing the user sees, however it only pops up once the user leaves the Modern UI and goes to the desktop, or runs a desktop based application.

Is there a way to get it to actually run at startup?

edit:  additional thought:  I wrote the program, can this be done if it was a Modern UI app?

Comment: Are you asking if a Windows Store/Modern UI application can launch into a desktop mode?

Comment: Not standard possible in Windows 8. It will be possible in Windows 8.1. There are some solutions on the net for Windows 8 to boot to the desktop but all have drawbacks. You can try some [here](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-boot-desktop-windows-8-skip-start-screen).

Comment: no, let me make my question a bit clearer.

Comment: Can't you just download Classic Shell and bypass the Modern UI when you log in?

Comment: @yassarikhan786 Unfortunately, that is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your program as default shell in Windows 8.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"Shell"="C:\Program Files (x86)\xx\xx\myprogram.exe"
```

or for the current user:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"Shell"="C:\Program Files (x86)\xx\xx\myprogram.exe"
```

If this doesn't work you need to add `cmd.exe /C` before the command.
i.e. `cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\xx\xx\myprogram.exe"`

This will completely bypass the Metro interface but you will loose all the standard shell stuff from explorer. (Don't know if you want that)
You will need to start the normal shell after exeting your program. (explorer.exe does not give you your desktop back so i don't know (yet) how to get the desktop and metro back)

(tested with Windows 8.1, so i don't know if this was possible in Windows 8)

**Edit**: You can also use "explorer.exe /select,explorer.exe" as shell-value. Then after login you'll see metro for a split second after which you get your desktop (with an explorer screen of your libraries.) Perhaps you'r auto-started application will be on top of that.

Comment: That's quite a hack you got there...